# Default class in jquery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to select div with button and it works, but how do I set a default one to show 
CODE HERE:

http://jsfiddle.net/LUKGt/5/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.textWord_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, There are three ways to do that

**First:** with css using `:not(:nth-child(1))` selector

```
.textWord_about{
   display : none;
}
.textWord_about:not(:nth-child(1)){  // 1 for the first index
   display : block;
}
```

**Second:** with js using `$('.textWord_about:not(:nth-child(1))')` selector

```
$('.textWord_about:not(:nth-child(1))').hide();
```

instead of

```
$('.textWord_about').hide();
```

**Third:** with js using `.eq(0).click() // 0 is an index for first`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.textWord_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
}).eq(0).click();
</script>
```

Comment: @RodolfoRodriguez Your're welcome. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You already have an anonymous function that hides everything except the one that was just clicked, that can be adapted to be used by the onclick as well as once when the page loads to set the default, like:

```
var defaultMenu = 'third';
menuSelect(defaultMenu);

$('.link').click(function() {
    menuSelect($(this).data("link"));
});

function menuSelect(link) {
    $('.textWord_about').hide(); 
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + link + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
}
```